# Alternate to STDEVPIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do `STDEVP` on a range of cells matching date range. I did not find `STDEVPIFS`. I would like to know how I can accomplish this?

We have excel rows like this. I need a formula for Column E which is standard deviation for 3 months multiplied by num days A. Num days cannot be 90 (3 months) as we need to include only working days and not saturday / sunday or holiday.

```
FORMULA1 = STDEVP(ColumnB[between[C1 & D1]])* SQRT(NUM A ROWS BETWEEN C1 & D1)

FORMULA2 = STDEVP(ColumnB[between[C2 & D2]])* SQRT(NUM A ROWS BETWEEN C2 & D2)
```

```
ROW     A         B          C             D           E 
1    03-01-2007            1-1-2007      31-3-2007  FORMULA1
2    04-01-2007 0.000495   1-4-2007      30-6-2007  FORMULA2  
3    05-01-2007 -0.00662   1-7-2007      30-9-2007
4    08-01-2007 0.002055   1-10-2007     31-12-2007
5    09-01-2007 -0.00055   1-1-2008      31-3-2008
6    10-01-2007 0.002059   1-4-2008      30-6-2008
     ..
     ..
60   30-03-2007 0.004350
     01-04-2007
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not a `FUNCTIONIF` or `FUNCTIONIFS` then using `{=FUNCTION(IF(...))}` instead can be the alternate. This is an array formula which uses the array returned by `IF` as a function parameter for the surrounding `FUNCTION`.

Such array formulas can be entered in `Excel` by typing in the formula without the curly brackets. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then the curly brackets are added automatically.

In your example, if column `A` contains only the working days, then the `{=STDEVP(IF...))}` would be:

```
{=STDEVP(IF(($A$1:$A$1000>=$C1)*($A$1:$A$1000<=$D1),$B$1:$B$1000))}
```

In array formulas one should not using whole column references since those contain more than one million cells in modern `Excel` versions.This would lead to performance issues. That's why do using `$A$1:$A$1000` instead of `$A:$A` and `$B$1:$B$1000` instead of `$B:$B`.

The counting the number of days would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1000,">="&$C1,$A$1:$A$1000,"<="&$D1)
```

I am not clear about the sense of your complete formula. That's why please put it together your own.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks for your quick response. I have problem only with the 1st formula {=STDEVP(IF(($A$1:$A$1000>=$C1)*($A$1:$A$1000<=$D1),$B$1:$B$1000))} I think the last parameter to IF returns all 1000 rows. Instead I want only 3 months data, for e.g. 60 or sometimes 61 or sometimes 59 rows (i.e. 3 months data)